# Launch Guitar Pro through my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I have an app that finds some guitar tabs and sets them up in a user friendly way. Things work, except for guitar pro tabs. (this is all from ultimate-guitar.com). When the user chooses a guitar pro tab, the webview that follows loads leads to a button page:

http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/d/david_gilmour/raise_my_rent_guitar_pro.htm

In my app, if I click that button, nothing happens. However, if I open the Guitar Pro app, click add, and go to ultimate-guitar, search the same song, and navigate to that same page I linked, the application asks if it would like to open that file, and does so successfully.

I would like to leverage the guitar pro app to my users if they have it installed and have the clicking of that button launch the guitar pro app, or any other solution where this could work would be fine. I don't know if there's some sort of notification system I can use, where the Guitar Pro app says that it can handle some certain files maybe and then I tell it that I have one, or what, but any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the Guitar Pro bundle, you should be able to discern whether the app is registered to respond to any custom URL schemes or file types.  The information will be found in the Info.plist or equivalent file.  For example, Good Reader is registered to open PDFs, so when you get a PDF attachment in Mail.app, it gives you the option to open it in that app.  And with the URLs, the YouTube and Maps apps are able to open.  The key you're looking for in the plist file is `CFBundleURLTypes`

Apple has a section about communicating with the custom URLs in their Standard Behaviors document.  A related excerpt:

> To communicate with an application
>   using a custom URL, create an NSURL
>   object with some properly formatted
>   content and pass that object to the
>   openURL: method of the shared
>   UIApplication object. The openURL:
>   method launches the application that
>   registered to receive URLs of that
>   type and passes it the URL. At that
>   point, control passes to the new
>   application.
>
> The following code fragment
>   illustrates how one application can
>   request the services of another
>   application (“todolist” in this
>   example is a hypothetical custom
>   scheme registered by an application):
>
> NSURL *myURL = [NSURL
>   URLWithString:@"todolist://www.acme.com?Quarterly%20Report#200806231300"];
>
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
>   openURL:myURL];

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html

Comment: Can you tell me how I might open the bundle? I've only got the app that I bought from iTunes and I have it on my phone...unfamiliar with how to look into it or anything. This seems like it could be the way to go so I hope you read this :)

Comment: I've managed to open the iPhone app and find the files, including the info.Plist. I don't see the CFBundleURLTypes exactly, but I do see two fields, document types which says "Guitar Pro File" and UTI information with .guitar pro file suffixes, and another key "Exported type UTIs" with each of those files described a bit more. Is there anything I can use there?

Comment: Well, it'll definitely be more complicated than the URLs -- a shame that it didn't look like those were obvious.  You're going to need to figure out two things: 
1) How to send a .guitar pro file to the app (must be doable, as GoodReader has an "Open In" which lists the available applications on the iPad to open a document in -- I just don't know the method call off the top of my head)
2) How to format the file to get the Guitar Pro app to accept it.
You might get lucky and the app might just open in a ready state if it's sent a file with that extension and mime type

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you 100% right, but did you look at `Implementing Custom URL Schemes`? This allows you to register a custom url scheme, which, when called, fires up you app.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html